# Populating a dropdown based on another dropdown in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dropdown

I have a issue in my Spring MVC web application. I have two dropdowns : categoryName and subCategoryName.
categoryName dropdown was populated using database values. Code for that is shown below and it works fine.

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddItem(Model model) {

    List<Map<String, Object>> listCat = categoryRepository.viewCategoryList();
    model.addAttribute("listCat",listCat);
    return "addItem";
}
```

JSP code:

```
<form:select class="form-control" id="selectCat" path="categoryName">
    <form:option value="-" label="--Select Category--"/>
    <c:forEach var="list" items="${listCat}">
        <form:option id="${list.key}" value="${list.get(\"name\")}">${list.get("name")}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

The dropdown subCategoryName has to be populated according to the value selected from the categoryName dropdown.For that I thought on having an ajax call on select change event as follows.

```
$("#selectCat").change(function(){
    var categoryNm = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:8443/admin/items/getSubcats",
        data: {"categoryNm " : categoryNm },
        success: function(data){
            var slctSubcat = $("#selectSubCat"), option= "";
            slctSubcat.empty();

            for(var sb =0; sb<data.length; sb++){
                option = option + "<option value='" + data[sb].name + "'>" +data[sb].name + "</option>";
            }
            slctSubcat.append(option);
        },
        error:function(){
           alert("error");
        }
   });

});
```

This ajax call will address the following controller method which contains the query for selecting the relevant sub-category list from the database.

```
//controller method to get relevant subcategory
@RequestMapping(value="/getSubcats",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> getSubcatList(@ModelAttribute("categoryNm") Category categoryNm){

    return categoryRepository.retrieveSubcatogories(categoryNm.getCategoryName());
}
```

The JSP code where I want to get the sub-category list populated is as below

But I am not getting the subCategory Dropdown populated. Could anybody figure me out this please

```
<form:select class="form-control" id="selectSubCat" path="subCategoryName">
    <form:option value="-" label="--Select sub-category--"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Have you checked your response `data`? What does it displays? Also you have `slctSubcat.empty();` which will remove even the default option from `select`. try adding this default option first, if it works fine then check your respose.

Comment: @VPK  No change though I removed `slctSubcat.empty();` Then I checked the response using an alert. It goes to the success function, but the response is empty (alert shows nothing)

Comment: Then you have to check the Controller method `getSubcatList()` whether it is returning correct value or not. Maybe you are getting null value from `categoryRepository.retrieveSubcatogories(categoryNm.getCategoryName());`

Comment: Is your controller called? are you getting data in ajax response?

Comment: @VPK yes...we are getting null value for `categoryRepository.retrieveSubcatogories(categoryNm.getCateg‌​oryName());`                                                                                               The case is as I think the parameter  `categoryNm.getCateg‌​oryName()`  is null.  There I want to pass the selected categoryName value (in first dropdown) from the jsp view to that controller method. Can you tell a way to do that.

Comment: @Naman actually no data in ajax response is getting. Its an empty alert.

Comment: @difna, you are sending the categoryNm parameter to the getSubcatList in `@ModelAttribute("categoryNm") Category categoryNm` here instead of `Category` use String object like `@RequestParam("categoryNm") String categoryNm`. Check if you are getting the selected value in the param.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getSubcats",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> getSubcatList(@RequestParam("categoryNm") String categoryNm){

    return categoryRepository.retrieveSubcatogories(categoryNm.getCategoryName());
}
```